# Response finishes before large process of records

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a process which can take tens of minutes to complete. We are looping through a grid, row by row, performing some calculations and saving to database. On the page we have a spinner to show the process is running. During the process after 5 minutes or so the spinner stops, but the process continues to perform the calculations and saves to the database. To the user it looks as though the process is complete.

Need some advice on how to keep that spinner a spinning until the process is complete.

We have this setting in the web.config:

Comment: <httpRuntime executionTimeout="200000" maxRequestLength="20000000"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "Frontend" is likely timing out.  For a process that runs that long you should consider using something like [Hangfire](https://hangfire.io) to ensure the process completes on the server side.

Other then that you would either need to use something like SignalR or polling to check a status flag of some sort to see when the process is complete.  For a process that runs that long I am not aware of a way to keep that http request open.  I would love to be corrected if there is.